# DNS look up fail

Tags: windows, dns

Within the past couple of weeks, (this is not happening every day) I have a "DNS look up fail" error while browsing Google Chrome, and then a yellow triangle will appear over my WiFi signal telling me I have Limited Access.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Also on a side note. I noticed that when I test connection with my PS3, sometimes it will say UPnP is not available, but will come back as available when it reconnects. Why is UPnP so fickle?

Comment: This is most likely a WiFi issue, not a DNS problem. Try restarting your router.

Comment: Man I feel like I have been having to do that a lot lately.

Comment: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-troubleshoot-your-wireless-network/

Comment: http://www.pcworld.com/article/260524/how_to_fix_your_wi_fi_network_7_tips.html

Comment: May not be a Wi-Fi issue. Quite possibly a LAN/ISP issue. Run a traceroute to some external site (e.g.: Google). Check your router's configuration to find the default gateway. If the gateway is your cable/DSL modem, check that device to get *its* gateway. Essentially, you need to determine the first external device along the path to the Internet. Then, run a continuous ping against that device and all other devices between it and your system. When the Internet connection drops, see which ones aren't responding.

Comment: ...That will help you isolate the problem, to determine if it's due to your WiFi or other LAN components or something your ISP manages. If the first external device is the only one that drops, it's something on your ISP's network. If anything else drops, it's something on your network (though it might be the modem, which is usually the ISP's device - up to you to know what's what). If nothing drops, it could still be on your ISP's network but may be somewhere external to them - still, call your ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Well I will try to do that when I have time.

But it happened to me again this morning .as well. But I tried something different this time. I put my laptop into sleep mode and I woke it up. When I did the yellow triangle over my Wi-Fi signal was gone and I was able to browse again.

Could it be actually an computer issue? The laptop I use it just a little over two years old.

Comment: Maybe a computer issue, do other computers have the same problem?

Comment: The only computer I use is my laptop. I have one downstairs but I rarely use it. The Other devices I use are mainly consoles, 3ds, and an IPAD.